# ATOMICally update multiple documents AND return them

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, atomic

In `MongoDB`, I'm looking for a way to ATOMICally update multiple documents and return all of the updated documents in a single call.

We can do all of the following in `MongoDB`:

- Atomically update one document and return the updated document: `findAndModify` or `findOneAndUpdate`
- Atomically update multiple documents: `update(...{multi: true}` or `updateMany`
- Query and return multiple documents: `find`

I haven't fond a way to update multiple documents and return them all in one call. Is there a way? I'm using `Mongoose` as the querying package.

Answer (score 4):

> Atomically update multiple documents: `update(...{multi: true}` or
>   `updateMany`

Unfourtantely that is false:

> [In MongoDB, write operations, e.g. db.collection.update(),
>   db.collection.findAndModify(), db.collection.remove(), are **atomic on**
>   **the level of a single document**.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/)

---

> [In MongoDB, a write operation is **atomic on the level of a single**
>   **document**, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents
>   within a single document.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

However, you can simulate a transaction to atomically update multiple documents by [*"using a two-phase commit approach"*](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) which is described in detail there.

You may also look at the `$isolated` operator, which [*"prevents a write operation that affects multiple documents from yielding to other reads or writes once the first document is written"*](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/isolated/#up._S_isolated)  but it [*"does not provide “all-or-nothing” atomicity for write operations"*](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/isolated/#up._S_isolated)

As a summary, it is not possible at mongodb level (nor the driver), but you can simulate it at your application level therefore return what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the atomic level. Based on the super useful links you sent I think the $isolated operator will provide what I need in this case for the update. A timetamp based approach similar to the two-phase commit you mention should work to ensure that the documents I return are the same as the ones which were just updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB v3.6 introduced sessions, which make this possible: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session/. I use mongoose, which makes using them quite simple. Something like this might work in your case:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();

let result;

// NOTE `withTransaction` expects a promise so I'm using `async`
await session.withTransaction(async () => {
  await SomeModel.update({
    foo: "bar"
  }, {
    $set: {
      quux:"baz"
    }
  }).session(session);

  result = await SomeModel.find({
    foo: bar
  }).session(session);
});

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested updateMany.

Testing1 :

Update 40K documents with updateMany (pull) , during execution , shutdown db suddenly , then some nodes passed(data was pulled out) , some failed (data was not pulled out in some level 5 nodes in tree) , restart db and run updateMany again , all passed and all data are correct now.

Testing 2:

Create an unique index on a field, insert some data, in updateMany method, some document will failed because of unique key violation.

My test2 result is : zero document was updated.

---

```
function insertData() {
  const dataSource = app.models.Entity.getDataSource();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dataSource.connector.connect((err, db) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error('.... error'));
        return;
      }
      const entityCollection = db.collection('Entity');
      // Create index
      entityCollection.createIndex({ age: 1 }, { unique: true })
      .then(() => {
        // Insert data
        const data = [
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            age: 1,
            type: 'test',
          },
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            age: 2,
            type: 'test',
          },
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            age: 3,
            type: 'test',
          },
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            age: 4,
            type: 'test',
          },
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            age: 5,
            type: 'test',
          },
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            age: 6,
            type: 'test',
          },
        ];
        return insertData(data);
      })
      .then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err2) => {
        reject(err2);
      });
    });
  });
}

function updateAge() {
  const dataSource = app.models.Entity.getDataSource();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dataSource.connector.connect((err, db) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error('...error'));
        return;
      }
      const entityCollection = db.collection('Entity');
      entityCollection.updateMany(
        { age: { $gt: 0 } },
        { $mul: { age: 2 } },
      ).then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err2) => {
        logger.error(`ERROR is ${err2}`);
        reject(err2);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

---

**The test result is : Zero documents are updated.** 
"msg":"ERROR is MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: content-base.Entity index: age_1 dup key: { : 2 }","v":1}
    1) updateMany test

0 passing (114ms)
  1 failing