# How to select all documents in MongoDB collection by parallel processes?

Tags: mongodb

I have multiple worker processes which select data from huge mongodb collection and performs some complex calculations.
Each document from MongoDB collection should be processed only once. 
Now I'm using following technic: I each worker marks and selects documents to process by .FindOneAndUpdate method. It finds a not marked document, marks it, and return to the worker. FindOneAndUpdate (findAndModify) is an atomic operation, so each document is selected only once.
Selecting documents one by one looks not so efficient. Is there some way to select by 100 documents and be sure document will be processed only once?
Is there some other, maybe MongoDB specific way to process a huge number of documents in parallel?

Comment: Uhm, using an aggregation or map/reduce first and do a findAndModify based on the results via a capped collection which acts as a queue? **edit**: with a tailable cursor?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided sample documents, the number of documents we are talking about and the calculations which need to be done to provide you with more concrete information.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

One way to solve that is by implementing segments for your data. Let's say you have 1M documents in your collection and 100 workers, find a field on your structure that can be equally-ish divided and pre-assign 10K documents for each worker.

But that process may be overkilled and will its efficiency could not really be better than query and process the documents individually. If you set an index on your `marked` field, the operation should be quite efficient as mongo will know where to look for unmarked documents.

I think the safest way to do what you need is actually processing them one by one. Mongo's atomicity is at a document level, so you may not find a way to lock several specific documents at the same time. [$isolated](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/isolated/#up._S_isolated) operator may help you in case that you may find a good way to segment the data for your workers.

This [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41073451/8364065) has useful links regarding atomicity and $isolated operator.